# Latex Formula error

Tags: latex, formula

I'm trying to create this formula in Latex:

[image]

The code i try using: `pos(v) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0 & v<0 \\ v & otherwise \end{matrix}\right.`

But for some reason my code keeps giving an error: 
Missing $ inserted.
< inserted text >
                     $
And yes i've tried placing the $ in some places, no result :(
Hopefully someone knows how to correct this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content that uses mathematics needs to be placed inside math mode (that is, surrounded by inline math symbols `$`...`$` or display math `\[`...`\]` or similar):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  pos(v) = \left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    0 & v < 0     \\
    v & otherwise
  \end{matrix}
  \right.
\]

\[
  \text{pos}(v) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $v < 0$} \\
    v & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

I propose using `cases` for displaying conditional functions. Also, use `\text` to set the appropriate textual content, rather than just setting text in math mode; the spacing will be horrible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. My first guess would be related to the environment. Did you enclose your formula in `$`? You have to do this in order to enter *math-mode*:

```
$pos(v) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}   0 & v<0 \\   v & otherwise \end{matrix} \right.$
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
\begin{equation}
  pos(v) = \left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    0 & v<0 \\
    v & otherwise
  \end{matrix}
  \right.
\end{equation}
```